AfterTrigger not working as expected as account not getting updated
I want the amount on all the opportunities related to an account to be aggregated on the Total_Amount__c field on the Account. Below mentioned is the Trigger on the opportunity(Just added for the afterInsert):
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before insert) {
Switch on trigger.OperationType{
    When After_Insert{
        OpportunityTriggerHandler.afterInsertUndelete(trigger.new);
    }

Helper class for the Trigger:
public class OpportunityTriggerHandler {
Public Static Void afterInsertUndelete(List<Opportunity> newOppty){
    set<Id> actIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    For(Opportunity oppty: newOppty){
        actIdSet.add(oppty.AccountId);
    }
    List<AggregateResult> agrResult = [SELECT Sum(Amount) sumOfAmmount, AccountId ids
                                 from Opportunity 
                                 Where AccountId IN :actIdSet group by AccountId];
    List<Account> actToBeUpdated = new List<Account>();
    For(AggregateResult agr : agrResult){
        Id actId = (Id)agr.get('ids');
        Decimal totalAmount = (Decimal)agr.get('sumOfAmmount');
        if(totalAmount == 0){
          Account act = new Account(Id =actId ,Total_Amount__c=0);  
          actToBeUpdated.add(act);
        }else{
         Account act = new Account(Id =actId ,Total_Amount__c=totalAmount);  
         actToBeUpdated.add(act);
        } 
    }
    Update actToBeUpdated;
}  
}

I was expecting the Total amount field (on Account) to be updated whenever I am inserting an opportunity with amount field not as blank but this is not happening (Total_Amount__c field remains blank)
can someone help me on this and let me know where I am going wrong?

Your trigger is declared as before insert, but you are trying to handle after insert logic. You should change the trigger declaration to after insert.

@TusharJadav might as well post it as an answer buddy.

Sorry gone through the entire code 10-20 times really did not look into the trigger context thanks a lot for the answer

Trigger Context: Your trigger is currently set to run in the before insert context. However, updating the Account record should be done in the after insert context. This is because the Account record must exist first before you can update it with the aggregated amounts from related Opportunities.

Sry gone through the entire code 10-20 times really did not look into the trigger context
thanks a lot for the answer
